# Create package with procedure Oracle

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, package

I have created a package with one procedure to delete any countries from a table where `country_ID` does not exist. I wrote this code:

```
CREATE PACKAGE cust_sa AS
  PROCEDURE del_cn3(c_cntry_id COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE)
  IS
      v_error_code NUMBER;
  BEGIN
     DELETE from countries WHERE country_id =c_cntry_id;
        
    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No such record');
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_error_code :=SQLCODE;
    IF v_error_code =-2292 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Organization ' ||
                                     TO_CHAR(c_cntry_id) ||
                                     ' site details defined for it.');
    END IF;
  END del_cn3;
END cust_sa;
/
```

However, I get the following two errors upon creating this package:

> (Line 4) Encountered the symbol V_ERROR_CODE when expecting one of
> the following: language
>
> (Last line) Encountered the symbol CUST_SA
> when expecting one of the following: ;

Why the errors appear and how to fix them?

Comment: your package (spec) should just have the procedure headers - you also have the implementation of the procedure - that goes in the PACKAGE BODY.

Comment: I hope you're going to add an "ELSE RAISE;" to your WHEN OTHERS exception hander.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your code on specification and body like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cust_sa AS
  PROCEDURE del_cn3(c_cntry_id COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE);
END cust_sa;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cust_sa AS

  PROCEDURE del_cn3(c_cntry_id COUNTRIES.COUNTRY_ID%TYPE) IS
    v_error_code NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM clients WHERE country_id = c_cntry_id;

    IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('No such record');
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_error_code := SQLCODE;
      IF v_error_code = -2292 THEN
        raise_application_error(-20004, 'Organization ' || to_char(c_cntry_id) || ' ...');
      END IF;
  END del_cn3;

END cust_sa;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
We should always foolow some old school defined steps before creating Packages 

1) Create Package Specs
2) Create Package Body.

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cust_sa
AS
  PROCEDURE del_cn3(
      c_cntry_id IN EMP.EMPNO%TYPE);
END cust_sa;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cust_sa
AS
PROCEDURE del_cn3(
    c_cntry_id IN EMP.EMPNO%TYPE)
IS
  v_error_code NUMBER;
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO =c_cntry_id;
  IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No such record');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  v_error_code   :=SQLCODE;
  IF v_error_code =         -2292 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20004,'Organization ' || TO_CHAR(c_cntry_id) || ' site details defined for it.');
  END IF;
END del_cn3;
END cust_sa;
```